# Hide a date if its less than today

Tags: php, datetime

so, is it possible to hide dates that are less than today using php explode? for example:

```
<select class="form-control nwthg mvcomment" name="dt" required>
    <?php $tags = explode(",",$res["on_dates"]);foreach ($tags as &$tag) {$tag = "<option value=\"$tag\" >$tag</option>";}echo implode(", ", $tags);?>
</select>
```

I want to display all dates but when date is older than today it would be hidden. 
I have all dates stored in mysql in one row separated with comma like this:

```
4-Oct-2019,5-Oct-2019,6-Oct-2019,10-Oct-2019,11-Oct-2019,13-Oct-2019,12-Oct-2019,25-Oct-2019,26-Oct-2019,18-Oct-2019,20-Oct-2019,31-Oct-2019,19-Oct-2019,24-Oct-2019,1-Nov-2019,2-Nov-2019,7-Nov-2019,10-Nov-2019,17-Nov-2019,19-Nov-2019
```

and yes, I'd like to hide all dates that are less than today

Comment: if you didn't have it in comma delimited form, you could have just simply did `WHERE on_dates > now()`, no more php `explode` and if conditions whatsoever

Comment: now you'd have to explode, array filter, convert all to unix timestamp, return all dates greater than `time()` then implode again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you can solve this filtering question:

```
$dates = '4-Oct-2019,5-Oct-2019,6-Oct-2019,10-Oct-2019,11-Oct-2019,13-Oct-2019,12-Oct-2019,25-Oct-2019,26-Oct-2019,18-Oct-2019,20-Oct-2019,31-Oct-2019,19-Oct-2019,24-Oct-2019,1-Nov-2019,2-Nov-2019,7-Nov-2019,10-Nov-2019,17-Nov-2019,19-Nov-2019';
$tags = explode(',', $dates);

$now = new DateTime('NOW');
$new = array_map(function($item) {
        return "<option value=\"$item\">$item</option>";
    }, array_filter($tags, function($date) use ($now) {
        return DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $date) < $now;
    })
);

print_r($new);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <option value="4-Oct-2019" >4-Oct-2019</option>
    [1] => <option value="5-Oct-2019" >5-Oct-2019</option>
    [2] => <option value="6-Oct-2019" >6-Oct-2019</option>
    [3] => <option value="10-Oct-2019" >10-Oct-2019</option>
    [4] => <option value="11-Oct-2019" >11-Oct-2019</option>
    [5] => <option value="13-Oct-2019" >13-Oct-2019</option>
    [6] => <option value="12-Oct-2019" >12-Oct-2019</option>
    [7] => <option value="25-Oct-2019" >25-Oct-2019</option>
    [8] => <option value="26-Oct-2019" >26-Oct-2019</option>
    [9] => <option value="18-Oct-2019" >18-Oct-2019</option>
    [10] => <option value="20-Oct-2019" >20-Oct-2019</option>
    [11] => <option value="31-Oct-2019" >31-Oct-2019</option>
    [12] => <option value="19-Oct-2019" >19-Oct-2019</option>
    [13] => <option value="24-Oct-2019" >24-Oct-2019</option>
    [14] => <option value="1-Nov-2019" >1-Nov-2019</option>
    [15] => <option value="2-Nov-2019" >2-Nov-2019</option>
    [16] => <option value="7-Nov-2019" >7-Nov-2019</option>
    [17] => <option value="10-Nov-2019" >10-Nov-2019</option>
)
```

Generating the desired markup:

```
printf('<select class="form-control nwthg mvcomment" name="dt" required>%s</select>', implode("", $new));
```

Results in:

```
<select class="form-control nwthg mvcomment" name="dt" required><option value="4-Oct-2019">4-Oct-2019</option><option value="5-Oct-2019">5-Oct-2019</option><option value="6-Oc
t-2019">6-Oct-2019</option><option value="10-Oct-2019">10-Oct-2019</option><option value="11-Oct-2019">11-Oct-2019</option><option value="13-Oct-2019">13-Oct-2019</option><opt
ion value="12-Oct-2019">12-Oct-2019</option><option value="25-Oct-2019">25-Oct-2019</option><option value="26-Oct-2019">26-Oct-2019</option><option value="18-Oct-2019">18-Oct-
2019</option><option value="20-Oct-2019">20-Oct-2019</option><option value="31-Oct-2019">31-Oct-2019</option><option value="19-Oct-2019">19-Oct-2019</option><option value="24-
Oct-2019">24-Oct-2019</option><option value="1-Nov-2019">1-Nov-2019</option><option value="2-Nov-2019">2-Nov-2019</option><option value="7-Nov-2019">7-Nov-2019</option><option value="10-Nov-2019">10-Nov-2019</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

One of them is to do as Kevin suggested and use a `WHERE` clause in the MYSQL query.

If you really have to hide them in another way, you can simply do:

```
$dates = '4-Oct-2019,5-Oct-2019,6-Oct-2019,10-Oct-2019,11-Oct-2019,13-Oct-2019,12-Oct-2019,25-Oct-2019,26-Oct-2019,18-Oct-2019,20-Oct-2019,31-Oct-2019,19-Oct-2019,24-Oct-2019,1-Nov-2019,2-Nov-2019,7-Nov-2019,10-Nov-2019,17-Nov-2019,19-Nov-2019';
$tags = explode(',', $dates);

foreach ($tags as $id => $tag) {
    $date = strtotime($tag); 
    if ($date < strtotime(date('d-M-Y'))) {
          unset($tags[$id]);
    } else {
        $tags[$id] = "<option value=\"$tag\" >$tag</option>"; 
    }
}
echo implode(",", $tags);
```

Comment: @SougataBose I have fixed it.

Comment: @SougataBose Not necessarily. We want older date than today, not older time. Imagine the case: Today is 10th of Nov. We have a date 10-11-2019. If we call `10-11-2019 < time`, time could be 10-11-2019 12:11, and then it would be a false positive.